# clockTick function is not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, oop, boost-asio, boost-thread

I am putting both the CPP and HPP files here and the error I receive:
I am adding the complete code here and the error I am encountering; kindly help.
Kindly help me in posting this question too.
CPP:

```
#include "TimeWindowCounter.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "../../Common/TimeAnalyser.hpp"

TimeWindowCounter::TimeWindowCounter()
{
    init();
}

void TimeWindowCounter::init()
{
    boost::atomic<bool> first_order_sent(false);
}

TimeWindowCounter::TimeWindowCounter(double currTime)
{
    first_order_sent = true;
    startTime = currTime;
    endTime = currTime;
    orderCount = 0;
    ind = 0;
    N = 1000;
    for (int j =0; j<= 99; j++ )
    numberofOrder[j] = 0;
}

TimeWindowCounter::~TimeWindowCounter()
{
}

void TimeWindowCounter::addOrder()
{
    orderCount++;
    numberofOrder[ind] = orderCount;
}

void TimeWindowCounter::clockTick(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/, boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* count, double* currTime)
{

    stopTime = *currTime;
    WindowSize = timeAnalyser.getDiffTime_rt(startTime, stopTime); 
    if (WindowSize.count()*1000 > N)
    startTime = startTime + (WindowSize.count()*1000-N);
    ind = (ind + 1) % 10;

    std::cout << *count << std::endl;
    ++(*count);

    t->expires_at(t->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1));
    t->async_wait(boost::bind(clockTick,boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count, currTime));       

} // 10ms or 100 times a second

int TimeWindowCounter::getNumOfOrders()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<= 99; i++)
    sum = sum + numberofOrder[i];
    return sum;
}


void TimeWindowCounter::run(){

io.run();

}

int main()
{

boost::asio::io_service io;

int count = 0;
TimeAnalyser timeAnalyser;
double currTime =  timeAnalyser.getClockTime();
TimeWindowCounter * timewindowCounter = new TimeWindowCounter();
boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));

t.async_wait(boost::bind(clockTick,boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t, &count, &currTime));

timewindowCounter->run();

for (int j = 0; j <=100000 ; j++)
timewindowCounter->addOrder();
std::cout << "Final count is " << count << std::endl;

}
```

HPP:

```
#ifndef TIMEWINDOWCOUNTER
#define TIMEWINDOWCOUNTER 

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "../../Common/TimeAnalyser.hpp"

using namespace std;

class TimeWindowCounter 
{

TimeAnalyser timeAnalyser;
boost::asio::io_service io;

public:

TimeWindowCounter();
~TimeWindowCounter();

TimeWindowCounter(double currTime);

boost::atomic<bool> first_order_sent;
boost::chrono::duration<double> interval;

double startTime;
double stopTime;
double endTime;
double currTime;

void init();

int numberofOrders; 
int orderCount; 

int numberofOrder[99];
int ind;

boost::chrono::duration<double> WindowSize;
int N; // WindowSize
void addOrder();
void clockTick(const boost::system::error_code&, boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* count, double* currTime); // 10ms or 100 times a second
int getNumOfOrders();
void timer_thread();
void run();

};

#endif
```

Compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o TA TimeWindowCounter.cpp -lboost_chrono -lboost_system
```

Error:

```
TimeWindowCounter.cpp: In member function ‘void TimeWindowCounter::clockTick(const boost::system::error_code&, boost::asio::deadline_timer*, int*, double*)’:
TimeWindowCounter.cpp:50:93: error: invalid use of non-static member function
     t->async_wait(boost::bind(clockTick,boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count, currTime));       
                                                                                             ^
TimeWindowCounter.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
TimeWindowCounter.cpp:80:26: error: ‘clockTick’ was not declared in this scope
 t.async_wait(boost::bind(clockTick,boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t, &count, &currTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding an instance member function.

You need to qualify the function name and pass a suitable "this" parameter as the first argument:

```
t->async_wait(boost::bind(&TimeWindowCounter::clockTick, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count, currTime));
```

and

```
t.async_wait(boost::bind(&TimeWindowCounter::clockTick, timewindowCounter, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t, &count, &currTime));
```

respectively.

#### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/104bdf97a166a42b)</kbd>**

```
#ifndef TIMEWINDOWCOUNTER
#define TIMEWINDOWCOUNTER

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/atomic.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <unistd.h>
//#include "../../Common/TimeAnalyser.hpp"

struct TimeAnalyser {
    double getClockTime() const { return 0; }
    boost::chrono::duration<double> getDiffTime_rt(double, double) const { return boost::chrono::milliseconds(1); }
};

using namespace std;

class TimeWindowCounter {

    TimeAnalyser timeAnalyser;
    boost::asio::io_service io;

  public:
    TimeWindowCounter();
    ~TimeWindowCounter();

    TimeWindowCounter(double currTime);

    boost::atomic<bool> first_order_sent;
    boost::chrono::duration<double> interval;

    double startTime;
    double stopTime;
    double endTime;
    double currTime;

    void init();

    int numberofOrders;
    int orderCount;

    int numberofOrder[99];
    int ind;

    boost::chrono::duration<double> WindowSize;
    int N; // WindowSize
    void addOrder();
    void clockTick(const boost::system::error_code&, boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* count,
                   double* currTime); // 10ms or 100 times a second
    int getNumOfOrders();
    void timer_thread();
    void run();
};

#endif
//#include "TimeWindowCounter.hpp"
#include <iostream>
//#include "../../Common/TimeAnalyser.hpp"

TimeWindowCounter::TimeWindowCounter() { init(); }

void TimeWindowCounter::init() { boost::atomic<bool> first_order_sent(false); }

TimeWindowCounter::TimeWindowCounter(double currTime)
{
    first_order_sent = true;
    startTime = currTime;
    endTime = currTime;
    orderCount = 0;
    ind = 0;
    N = 1000;
    for (int j = 0; j <= 99; j++)
        numberofOrder[j] = 0;
}

TimeWindowCounter::~TimeWindowCounter() {}

void TimeWindowCounter::addOrder()
{
    orderCount++;
    numberofOrder[ind] = orderCount;
}

void TimeWindowCounter::clockTick(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/, boost::asio::deadline_timer* t, int* count,
                                  double* currTime)
{

    stopTime = *currTime;
    WindowSize = timeAnalyser.getDiffTime_rt(startTime, stopTime);
    if (WindowSize.count() * 1000 > N)
        startTime = startTime + (WindowSize.count() * 1000 - N);
    ind = (ind + 1) % 10;

    std::cout << *count << std::endl;
    ++(*count);

    t->expires_at(t->expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1));
    t->async_wait(boost::bind(&TimeWindowCounter::clockTick, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, t, count, currTime));

} // 10ms or 100 times a second

int TimeWindowCounter::getNumOfOrders()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
        sum = sum + numberofOrder[i];
    return sum;
}

void TimeWindowCounter::run() { io.run(); }

int main()
{

    boost::asio::io_service io;

    int count = 0;
    TimeAnalyser timeAnalyser;
    double currTime = timeAnalyser.getClockTime();
    TimeWindowCounter* timewindowCounter = new TimeWindowCounter();
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));

    t.async_wait(boost::bind(&TimeWindowCounter::clockTick, timewindowCounter, boost::asio::placeholders::error, &t, &count, &currTime));

    timewindowCounter->run();

    for (int j = 0; j <= 100000; j++)
        timewindowCounter->addOrder();
    std::cout << "Final count is " << count << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
Final count is 0
```